# NSMutableDictionary using objectAtIndex

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I am new to Xcode and I have created a `NSMutableDictionary *dIc` with following data:

Keys : ID , Name

Data :

- ID = 1, Name = John
- ID = 2, Name = Smith

I want to access `dIc` with specific row. I want this result for example :

Name = Smith.

I tried :

```
-(void)initiateArrays
{
    dIc =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self initiateArrays];
    [self callingWebSrvc];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
-(void)callingWebSrvc
{

    NSInteger i=0;


    do {
        self.selectedRowId = [[mainMenuID objectAtIndex:i]integerValue];
        [self getItemListFromWebSrvc];
    i++;
    } while (i<= mainMenuData.count - 1);

}
-(void) getItemListFromWebSrvc
{
    //............ Request ....................................>>>
    .
    .
    .
    //............ Response ....................................>>>
    NSInteger i = 0;
    do {
        elm = [xmlDataTable objectAtIndex:i];
        //Set Object into Arrays

        [dIc setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:selectedRowId] forKey:@"Id"];
        [dIc setObject:[elm childNamed:@"Name"].value forKey:@"Name"];

        NSArray *keys = [rowArray allKeys];

        // values in foreach loop
        for (NSString *key in keys) {
            NSLog(@"%@ is %@",key, [dIc objectForKey:key ]);
        }

        i=i+1;
    } while (i <= xmlDataTable.count-1);
}
-(void)showResult
{
    NSString *anObject = [[dIc objectForKey:@"Name"  ] objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"The Value is = %@",anObject );
}
```

but it's not working.

when i call [self showResult]; i got the following error:
    -[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b9a7f0
    2014-02-26 00:53:57.718 iWish[3311:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized     selector sent to instance 0x8b9a7f0'

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to populate the dict?

Comment: 'code' dIc =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];                                              [dIc setObject:[elm childNamed:@"Id"].value forKey:@"Id"];
                [dIc setObject:[elm childNamed:@"Name"].value forKey:@"Name"];

Comment: It would be better if you post that code in your original question - it's more readable. Also:
- what's elm? (post relevant code)
- what's not working? What's the expected and actual result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
NSString *anObject = [[dIc objectForKey:@"Name"  ] objectAtIndex:1];
```

The first object in this story, `[dIc objectForKey:@"Name"  ]`, is an NSString. You are then saying `objectAtIndex:1` to an NSString - and that is a no-no.

Comment: so how can i access the value in array in specific index ?

Comment: hi matt, thanks for your reply i want to view the data inside "dIc" NSMutabledictionary , how i can do that

Comment: You are viewing it. What you get out of it depends on what you put into it. You can NSLog dIc itself to see its structure.